# I am American and have a D visa multi-entry for Italy

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, italy, long-stay-visas

I'm an American with a D multi-entry visa for Italy for 1 year. Can I visit the USA for 2 months and come back, or is there a time length limit on how long I can leave Italy and return?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you think there is a time limit?

Comment: Thank you, I do hope that I can go back to USA and work some and return to Italia!

Answer (score 1):

As long as your visa (or residence permit card if you have one) remains valid, you're free to exit and re-enter Italy.